# how to install ros on unbuntu 13.10

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to follow the "Ubuntu install of ROS Hydro" guidance to install,but failed.
Can ROS be applied on Ubuntu 13.10?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117906/how-to-install-ros-on-unbuntu-13.10/) by [chi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10856/chi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-01-14**:
what kind of error you recieved?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-15**:
failed says nothing! What exactly did you do? What did you observe? What did you expect to happen and worked out differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this REP (REP 003)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html), Hydro is targeted to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 12.10 and 13.04, not for 13.10.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1